# Texstudio failure to view TikZ output compiled by XeLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, debugging

Texsudio successfully shows the result of the following `MWE` compiled by pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 3pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw]  (a){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, texstudio's preview window shows nothing when I use XeLaTeX (even after pressing `F7`).

[image]

Oddly enough, if I add a text to the label field of the node above, the quoted issue gets resolved.

[image]

Here is some details about my setup:

Machine: Windows 10

Distribution: MikTeX 21.8

Texstudio: 2.12.10

`\pgfversion`: 3.1.9a

Is this a bug?

Comment: With the same MiKTeX, but use Sumatra for pfd viewer I can't confirm your problem. Compilation result using LaXeTeX is as expected.

Comment: This is a texstudio (or poppler) problem which has been fixed (see [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/pull/580)) in texstudio 2.12.16. The problem is that, the built-in pdf viewer fails rendering very small PDF files.